# Implementing templates, I'm having issues "matching function definitions to existing declarations"

Tags: c++, templates

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. The syntax is what I've used before (taken from example classes from my class) and haven't had any issues. The only difference is I'm using Visual Studio 2013 now. I keep getting this error when I attempt to build my solution (it happens for all the methods so clearly I must have some syntax wrong?)...

```
error C2244: 'node<T>::getItem' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>          c:\users\milan\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\threadedbst\threadedbst\node.h(19) : see declaration of 'node<T>::getItem'
1>          definition
1>          'T node::getItem(void)'
1>          existing declarations
1>          'T node<T>::getItem(void)'
```

Here is the simple node class I was making using a template.

```
using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node<T> class: 
//   -- 
//
// Assumptions:
//   -- <T> maintains it's own comparable functionality
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T>
class node {

public:
    node(T* value); //constructor
    node(const node<T>&); //copy constructor
    void setFrequency(int); //sets the frequency
    int getFrequency(); //returns the frequency
    T* getItem(); //returns the item

private:
    T* item;
    int frequency;
    node<T>* leftChild;
    node<T>* rightChild;
    bool leftChildThread;
    bool rightChildThread;
};

//-------------------------- Constructor ------------------------------------
template <typename T>
node<T>::node(T* value) {
    item = value;
    frequency = 1;

}

//-------------------------- Copy ------------------------------------
template <typename T>
node<T>::node(const node<T>& copyThis) {
    item = copyThis.value;
    frequency = copyThis.frequency;
}

//-------------------------- setFrequency ------------------------------------
template <typename T>
void node<T>::setFrequency(int num) {
    frequency = num;
}

//-------------------------- getFrequency ------------------------------------
template <typename T>
int node<T>::getFrequency() {
    return frequency;
}

//-------------------------- getItem ------------------------------------
template <typename T>
T* node<T>::getItem() {
    return item;
}
```

Comment: `node leftChild;  node rightChild;` how can this work?

Comment: It builds perfectly fine for me under VS 2012. What I notice however is that you do not specify the type of node when you use it (it should probably be `node<T>` instead of `node`)

Comment: Made the suggested change but that doesn't change the errors I'm having. I think I'll have to abandon VS 2013. I copied it into jGrasp and it all compiled without issue. What a waste of time.

Comment: You cannot have a `node` inside of a `node`. You would have turtles all the way down. Other than that, [the declaration deems to be OK](http://ideone.com/YzZs4F).

Comment: Do you maybe have an unclosed `{` somewhere?

Comment: With the noted errors corrected (`leftChild` and `rightChild` changed to pointers) it compiles fine with VC++ 18 (i.e., the C++ compiler in VS 2013). If it's not compiling for you with that compiler, you must have a problem in installation or configuration.

Comment: @JerryCoffin With the noted errors corrected I still get the error:

visual studio 2013\projects\threadedbst\threadedbst\node.h(63): error C2244: 'node<T>::getItem' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
1>          c:\users\milan\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\threadedbst\threadedbst\node.h(21) : see declaration of 'node<T>::getItem'
1>          definition
1>          'T *node::getItem(void)'
1>          existing declarations
1>          'T *node<T>::getItem(void)'

:/

Comment: Sorry for that unformated mess, not good with the comments here... basically it says my methods are "T *node::getItem(void)" but the definitions are "T *node<T>::getItem(void)"

Comment: @MilanNovaković I'm struggling to understand why you converted `T` to `T*` in the first place. As near as I can see it had nothing to do with your original problem, and worse, it makes things like your copy-ctor, assignment op, etc, non longer just useless, but now downright dangerous. Is the code, and reported error, both in-sync and *exactly* what you're using now? (I don't see how it is, since `item = copyThis.value;` in your copy-ctor couldn't compile; there is no `value` member of `node<T>`).

Comment: Because it's better to pass around pointers to objects as opposed to the whole object as it's less resource intensive? I can change it back if that's not the case. None of these details had any effect on the error messages (either causing them or fixing them). Think people are getting caught up on the wrong things. The code both BEFORE and currently has the exact same errors. Every function throws an error saying that it's definition doesn't match the declaration. This happened before the change and after the change.

Comment: Are these errors showing up when you *compile* the code, or just from Intellisense?

Comment: When I build the solution yes. jGrasp however doesn't seem to complain (if I copy and paste over and compile it there).

Comment: Your code is valid, there are [no compilation errors](http://ideone.com/Vf3c4p) (but do change `T*` back to `T` unless you enjoy headaches). If your compiler complains, it's pretty much broken; use some other compiler.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't allow self-nest type, you need to use pointer

```
template <typename T>
class node {
    .... 
    node<T>* leftChild;  //pointer
    node<T>* rightChild;
    ...
};
```

see [live](http://ideone.com/NYm6PT) sample

Comment: Thanks that was simply something I missed as I typed it out. Has no effect on the errors I'm having.

Comment: Now you get more troubles. some T types are value type, some are pointer

Comment: @MilanNovaković your updated copy still doesn't work. There is no `node<T>::node(T* value)` declared in the class template declaration.

Comment: Sorry I had missed a T when converting it to pointer. Now it should all be good. It's all beside the point however since I'm still getting the same error regardless of any of these other details. Since jGrasp wasn't complaining I think I'll install and try with VS 2012.